# Find the sum of $\binom{100}1 + 2\binom{100}2 + 4\binom{100}3 +8\binom{100}4+\dots+2^{99}\binom{100}{100}$

Tags: combinatorics

Find the sum of 
$\binom{100}1 + 2\binom{100}2 + 4\binom{100}3 +8\binom{100}4+\dots+2^{99}\binom{100}{100}$

How you guys work on with this question? With the geometric progression? Combination? Or anyother way to calculate?

Comment: Have you tried expanding $(1 + 2)^{100}$ using the binomial theorem?

Comment: There was a misplaced parenthesis in the original question. Please check that the latexification was done right.

Comment: Thx for help in edit my question....

Comment: It looks like you have some extra parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{r=1}^{100}2^{r-1}\binom{100}r=\frac12\sum_{r=1}^{100}2^r\binom{100}r=\frac12\left[(1+2)^{100}-1\right]$$